# Scrollable card-list in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I need to implement card-list with scroll down button in Vuejs. What's the best way to do that? What npm packages I can use?

[image: card list]

Comment: how about [this](https://ederdiaz.dev/blog/making-a-scrolling-card-list-wot-w/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put id = "content" in the parent div and on the button you call the scroll function

```
const containerMovie = document.getElementById("content");

containerMovie.scrollBy({
  top: -600,
  left: 0,
  behavior: "smooth"
});
```

Comment: Got your idea, thanks. 
I think it'd be better to use $refs instead of touching DOM that way